# Positioning a C3 chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, c3.js

I am having difficulty positioning my c3 chart. I have three divs in each row and attaching a separate chart to each of them. However, as you can see there is a lot of gap between the top and the bottom row. Any pointers how do remove this? I have tried positioning the div but it does not work.

Also, in the top row, my charts appear at different positions. I am unable to align them.

[image]

Comment: have you tried translate to position?

Comment: I am not sure where you add it to the c3 code. I know how to use it with D3 though

Comment: I don't think there is any way in c3 checked the API. guess need to go the d3 way in the `onrendered` callback.

Comment: Can you please provide jsFiddle or codepen sample code?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?